# Using .class methods in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, class, import

I have two classes, Phone.class and Time.class. I would like to use their methods for my project in eclipse, but I cant figure out how to do it successfully. How do you import the .class files so that I can use their methods in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the folder containing both classes to the build path for the project: right-click on the project in the Package Explorer window and select the *Build Path* option, then select the *Configure Build Path* option. The **Libraries** tab has *Add Class Folder* and *Add External Class Folder* options: use the first if the folder with the class files is already part of the project, otherwise use the second. Select the folder and then hit *OK* and you should be good to go.

Comment: I can see the exception class that I imported, but I still can't use the methods from the 2nd class. Do you know why this is?